# Javascript equivalent of JEB

Tags: debugging, java, deobfuscation, javascript

In case you already know, there is a full-feature decompiler for Java/Android called JEB (https://www.pnfsoftware.com/)

Some of the most important features include the ability to rename identifiers and click-through program trace functionality and cross referencing.

Is there such an equivalent IDE for Javascript? Commercial or free.